# A mutable container of immutable objects in C++

Tags: c++

I'd like to have something equivalent to a C++ std::vector, where the underlying objects are immutable.  So I can push_back() items to add them to the vector, etc.  An actual std::vector maintains an array underneath that's bigger than the size of the vector, filled with default constructed objects, and when you push_back(), it does an assignment to an element in the array.  My immutable objects don't have a default constructor, and assignment is a mutating operation, so that's out too.

I can do a `vector<boost::optional<T>>`, but that's a messy interface because I only want to put validly constructed objects into the vector, and only get those out of the vector.

I thought boost had something like this, but I couldn't find it.  Does something like this exist?

Comment: At least in C++11, vectors work as you want them to.  You can use `emplace_back()`.

Comment: Can you store smart pointers to the actual immutable objects in your vector?

Comment: The way you're describing `vector<T>` does not match exactly how it works. Does your type have move and/or copy constructors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conception of how the `vector` works is incorrect.

The vector uses the allocator to allocate raw memory. That raw memory does *not* contain default constructed objects--it's just raw memory.

When you do a `push_back` (for example) it then uses a placement `new` to construct an object into the raw memory. Likewise, when you `erase` an object, it will end up directly invoking its destructor to turn the object back into raw memory.

With a current (C++11 or later) implementation of `std::vector`, your object doesn't need to support default construction or assignment. Supporting move construction and move assignment should be sufficient. To put them to use, you'd want to use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` though.

Comment: `push_back()` on an rvalue also uses move construction.

Comment: @Angew: True. And likewise, `emplace_back` can do a copy if you have a type that doesn't support moving--but I'd prefer code to reflect the real intent, so if you plan on a move-only type, I'd rather see `emplace_back`, even when `push_back` would actually work.

Comment: OK, I like the "code what you mean" train of thought, so this makes perfect sense.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Doesn't supporting move assignment violate the stated immutability constraint? After all, assigning to the object would modify it, right? Or maybe you distinguish between the immutability of an object versus immutability of its storage?